# How to conditionally enclose a list of reviews with `reverse_related_entries`?

Tags: templates, related-entries

If there are review entries related to the current entry then I would like to display it as follows:

```
<aside id="reviews">
    <h3>Reviews</h3>
{reverse_related_entries channel="review"}
    <article>
        <h4>{title}</h4>
        {review_body}
    </article>
{/reverse_related_entries}
</aside>
```

If there are no reviews then I do not want to display anything.

I could just add a JavaScript which removes the empty "Reviews" section, but I would rather it wasn't outputted if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wouldn't this work?

```
{reverse_related_entries channel="review"}
{if count == "1"}
<aside id="reviews">
<h3>Reviews</h3>
{/if}
<article>
    <h4>{title}</h4>
    {review_body}
</article>
{if count == total_results}</aside>{/if}
{/reverse_related_entries}
```

Comment: Interesting thanks! Do you know off the top of your head if `{if count % 4 == 0}` works?

Comment: Pretty sure it doesn't - but you could always enable php in your template and do it that way.

Comment: Yeah, not without PHP in the template or a Plugin. If you don't want to use PHP in your template then [Modulo Operator](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/modulo-operator)  or [SugarEE](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/surgeree) will enable you to use modulo in your templates. There is also the native [switch variable](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#switch) which is handy but can get messy depending on what you need to do.

Comment: More on the topic of modulo and `{switch}` can be found in the answers to [this question](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/q/33/22).

Answer (score 0):

> Do you know off the top of your head if {if count % 4 == 0} works

I'd never considered the EE could use modulus. I haven't tested but a quick look at the docs and it isn't listed:
http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/conditionals.html#comparison-operators

I've done this many time by just enabling PHP for the template.

*NB Not sure how can you to reply to a thread of someone else's answer.